# Auto mapper Exception

Tags: entity-framework, automapper

I am trying to map my Models and i am getting error

```
        AtpWorldTourEntities obj = new AtpWorldTourEntities();
        Player _player;
        List<tblPlayer> _tblPlayer = obj.tblPlayers.ToList();
        //.FirstOrDefault();
        AutoMapper.Mapper.CreateMap<tblPlayer, Player>();
        _player = Mapper.Map<Player>(_tblPlayer);
        return View(_player);



Missing type map configuration or unsupported mapping.    
Mapping types:
List`1 -> Player
System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[MVCAPP.Models.tblPlayer, MVCAPP, Version=1.0.0.0,     
Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]] -> MVCAPP.Models.Player
Destination path:
Player
Source value:
System.Collections.Generic.List`1[MVCAPP.Models.tblPlayer]
```

Comment: Do you want to return a single Player or List<Player>?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't map a `Player` to a `List<Player>`. Since you want to return a `List<Player>` you should map to a list instead:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<tblPlayer, Player>();
_player=Mapper.Map<List<tblPlayer>, List<Player>>(_tblPlayer);
```